# Android write file to Internal Storage issue

Tags: android, file

I have a little issue with writing a file in Internal Storage in Android. I'm trying to do it from a helper class which is not an activity. Here is the code I'm using :

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("media", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(media.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

And it throws me a null pointer exception at the first line. I tried with `this.context.openFileOutput("media",this.context.MODE_PRIVATE);`  & `this.context.openFileOutput("media",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` but nothing helps.

Any idea how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I had the same issue and here is the solution :

You can use this :

**Activity1.java**

```
onCreate()

helperClass mHelper= new helperClass(CallingActivity.this);
```

**helperClass.java**

```
//declare a context
context refContext;

//constructor
public helperClass(context mContext)
{
   refContext=mContext;
}

//and you code

    hash= jsonObj.getString("hash");
    Log.w("CLIENT AUTH HASH","SHOW CLIENT AUTH HASH : "+hash);                  
    FileOutputStream out = refContext.openFileOutput("autohash",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    out.write(hash.getBytes());
    out.close();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try get context first

"context = getApplicationContext()"

Answer (score 0):

Verifies that the activity from which the instance of the class helper pass the reference of context, you specify a little more the scenary, for example, who inherits the helper class or how do you set the instance of the context attribute?.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do that in class which extends a custom class.And I can't use Context context=this; cause it showing me an error...and I think that context is returning null.